# Cron and FTP daemons crashing randomly in RHEL

Tags: redhat, cron, service

Not sure where to start in troubleshooting this. I'm not finding anything indicating an issue in ProFTP logs or in /var/log/messages. So I do apologize for not having more information to give.

**Overview:**
RHEL 5 shared web server w/ Plesk 10. Uptime of 600 days, never had this issue previously, haven't made any changes to the system recently. Received complaints relating to both FTP and automated task issues. Both services were "stopped" (`proftpd` and `crond`). Restarted `xinetd` and `crond`, which temporarily solved the issues. Ran a `yum update kernel*`. The next day, they are down again.

This isn't really my thing, and I'm a bit lost. I'd appreciate any help you can give about how to troubleshoot the issue, what logs to check, or what applications might help me monitor the services. Basically I'm lacking any meaningful information as to why this is happening.

Thanks so much guys! I'll happily post more info if needed.. Just not sure what would be useful.

Comment: Kernel updates require a reboot to enable them.  Also many glibc based programs may also require a restart or reboot.   Given the uptime, you may have file system errors as well. I suggest a reboot to start.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Thanks, I actually wasn't aware of that.. but of course it makes sense. Guess I'll give that a shot. Was hoping to avoid downtime. Softlayer basically couldn't help either.. hopefully that solves it or I'm pretty much SOL on this one.

Comment: We use Ksplice on the softlayer servers we manage.  That avoids us from having to do reboots while allowing us to update the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend rebooting and doing a file system check.  I have seen file system errors lead to unusual behavior.

If that does not resolve the issue, then temporarily disable any firewalls to see if they are interfering.

Lastly, run your FTP client in debug mode to see what is happening when the connection stops.

Also noted that on Plesk, proftpd runs under xinted.  If you have a lot of connections, you may need to adjust xinted to allow more instances.